# Extact datatype from a column value varchar SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
table1{
   id: int,
   desc: varchar(50),
   type: varchar(50)
}

table2{
   id(tableX): varchar(20),
   id2(table1): int,
   value: sql_variant
}
```

Table1 have this row:

| id | desc | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | varchar(20) |
| 2 | Birthday | datetime |

I want to insert values into table2 using the type defined on table1.

Something like this:

```sql
insert into table1 (id,id2,value) values('test',1,cast('John' as (select type from table1 where id = 1)))
```

Desired table2:

| id | id2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000000x | 1 | john |
| 000000x | 2 | 12/03/1960 |

I'm looking for the SQL equivalent of this C# code:

```cs
Type type = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
object value = 12;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ChangeType(value, type));
```

is it  possible to do this? is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like another EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) database. Is there a good reason for you to be using this anti-pattern?

Comment: @Dai The table1 will have +20 rows with diferent types. I want all types on the same column (some alternatives are multiple columns like: Value_varchar, Value_datetime, etc)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that. Tell your manager or client that the database's design is fundamentally broken and you should redesign it _good_ instead of keeping a bad system around for longer than it should be. If you're only storing ~20 rows then you _definitely should not_ be using the EAV anti-pattern.

Comment: @Dai What pattern should i use?

Comment: There is no pattern; instead you just design the tables to directly represent the data that they _actually_ contain - which does mean potentially adding dozens or more tables to your database, but that shouldn't be a problem if you have the right namespacing/schemas set-up. Any existing software/client software/reports that do need that exact view of data (with the `variant` column) then that can be easily done with a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `CAST` function dynamically. You could wrap the cast for each datatype inside `CASE` but the return datatype will be the one with highest priority and, for example, "John" cannot be converted to a date.

In theory, you could do this and it should work:

```
SELECT CASE type
       WHEN 'varchar(20)' THEN CAST(CAST('x' AS varchar(20)) AS sql_variant)
       WHEN 'datetime'    THEN CAST(CAST('x' AS datetime   ) AS sql_variant)
       WHEN ...
END
```

Here is a little [proof of concept](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8267f726cc84310cf8725074304a4e51).